# Ctrl+C not reliably terminating Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script that prompts the user for a directory and copies multiple files from this directory to another one. To do this, I have a simple loop, using labels and `set /p` for input. The problem is that trying to get out of this loop by pressing `ctrl+c` doesn't always work.

```
:checkloop

@set /p READMEPATH=Please enter the location of readme.txt: 

@if not exist "%READMEPATH%\README.txt" goto somethingmissing

@goto allfound

:somethingmissing
@echo Can't find readme in directory "%READMEPATH%"
@goto checkloop

:allfound

@echo Okay, found
```

Sample output is something like

```
Please enter the location of readme.txt:
Can't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CCan't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CCan't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CCan't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CCan't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CCan't find readme in directory ""
Please enter the location of readme.txt: ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Hitting ctrl+c repeatedly acts as if I hit enter and the script continues, until it finally works. The number of tries needed is variable; sometimes it works right away, sometimes 2-3, rarely it takes 7+ times.

OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I'd guess you'll have to check %errorlevel% after the SET call to see that it failed.

Comment: @HansPassant The problem of the `%errorlevel%` is, that it's set to 1 for CTRL-C and also for an empty input.

Comment: Congratulations, both good reasons to stop trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if READMEPATH is defined.

```
:checkloop
set "READMEPATH="
set /p READMEPATH=Please enter the location of readme.txt: 
if not defined READMEPATH exit /b
```

But this can't detect the difference between pressing CTRL-C and ENTER for an empty line.

Comment: That will work as a suitable workaround, although I am genuinely interested in why ctrl+c isn't working here. I don't think ctrl+c and ENTER being the same will be a problem for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is based in getKey version 1.3, written by Dave Benham, and originally posted at [Read key presses via REPLACE - New functions :getKey, :getAnyKey, :getMaskedInput](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7396)

More complex batch, but as a proof of concept it distinguish between CTRL+C and ENTER.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F %%# in ('forfiles /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo 0x03"') do set "CTRLC=%%#" & rem capture CTRL-C char
for /F %%# in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') do set "CR=%%#"                         & rem capture carriage return char
for /F %%# in ('"prompt $H&for %%@ in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%#"                                         & rem capture backspace char
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%# in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%@ in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%#" & rem capture DEL char

:checkloop
cls & set "READMEPATH="
<nul set/P "=Please enter the location of readme.txt: " 

:getPath
call :getKey key

if "%key%" equ "%CTRLC%" exit/B & rem or whatever you wanna do
if "%key%" equ "%CR%" goto:done 

if "%key%" equ "%BS%" (
  <nul set/P=%DEL%
  set "READMEPATH=%READMEPATH:~0,-1%"
) else (
  <nul set/P=%key%
  set "READMEPATH=%READMEPATH%%key%"
)

goto getPath

:done
if not defined READMEPATH exit/B
@if not exist "%READMEPATH%\README.txt" goto somethingmissing

@goto allfound

:somethingmissing

echo(&echo( Can't find readme in directory "%READMEPATH%"
pause
@goto checkloop

:allfound

@echo Okay, found
endlocal
exit/B

::getKey  KeyVar  [ValidVar]
::
:: Read a keypress representing a character between 0x00 and 0xFF and store the
:: value in variable KeyVar. Null (0x00), LineFeed (0x0A), and Carriage Return
:: (0x0D) will result in an undefined KeyVar. On Windows 10, Ctrl-Z (0x1A) will
:: also result in an undefined KeyVar. The simplest way to get an undefined
:: KeyVar is to press the [Enter] key.
::
:: The optional ValidVar variable defines the values that will be accepted.
:: If not given or not defined, then all characters are accepted. If given
:: and defined, then only characters within ValidVar are accepted. The first
:: character within ValidVar should either be 0, meaning ignore undefined KeyVar,
:: or 1, meaning accept undefined KeyVar. The remaining characters represent
:: themselves. For example, a ValidVar value of 0YNyn will only accept upper
:: or lower case Y or N. A value of 1YNyn will additionally accept [Enter] etc.
::
:: Any value (except null) may be entered by holding the [Alt] key and pressing
:: the appropriate decimal code on the numeric keypad. For example, holding
:: [Alt] and pressing numeric keypad [1] and [0], and then releasing [Alt] will
:: result in a LineFeed.
::
:: The only way to enter a Null is by holding [Ctrl] and pressing the normal [2]
::
:: An alternate way to enter control characters 0x01 through 0x1A is by holding
:: the [Ctrl] key and pressing any one of the letter keys [A] through [Z].
:: However, [Ctrl-A], [Ctrl-F], [Ctrl-M], and [Ctrl-V] will be blocked on Win 10
:: if the console has Ctrl key shortcuts enabled.
::
:: This function works properly regardless whether delayed expansion is enabled
:: or disabled.
::
:: :getKey version 1.3 was written by Dave Benham, and originally posted at
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7396
::
:: This work was inspired by posts from carlos and others at
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6382
::
:getkey
set "%1="
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
  'replace.exe ? . /u /w'
) do for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%B in ("%%A") do (
  endlocal
  if "%%B" equ "" (set "%1=^!") else set "%1=%%B"
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "!%2!" neq "" (
  if not defined %1 if "!%2:~0,1!" equ "0" (endlocal&endlocal&goto :getKey) else exit /b
  set "getKey.key=!%1!"
  set "mask=!%2:~1!"
  if not defined mask endlocal&endlocal&goto :getKey
  if "!getKey.key!" equ "=" (
    set "test=a!mask!"
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!test!") do if /i "!test:%%A=%%A!" equ "!test!" endlocal&endlocal&goto :getKey
  )
  for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("!getKey.key!") do if "!mask:*%%A=!" equ "!mask!" endlocal&endlocal&goto :getKey
)
exit /b
```

Comment: The only drawback of this solution is, that it can't receive input from copy&paste, as `replace` seems to clear the input buffer after reading one character

Comment: @jeb Right. As you noticed, even the `errorlevel` check fails, as is set to 1 for `CTRL+C` and also for empty input. So it never rains to everyone's taste. I was only trying to check whether `CTRL+C` and `ENTER` could be distinguised. BTW, is the first time I was able to get the `CTRL+C` capture somehow working.